# Django clean() change field requirement

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, model

I want to change the requirement of some modelForm fields as shown below.
`certs` is a checkbox. If this checkbox is "True" the `ca`,`cert` and `key` fields shall be required. If not, they shall be left blank (`null=True` is set in models).

```
class CreateMVPConnectionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MVPConnections
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['created_by_user', 'parent_project_id']


    def clean(self):
        print("clean started")
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        certs = cleaned_data.get('certs')
        ca = cleaned_data.get('ca')
        cert = cleaned_data.get('cert')
        key = cleaned_data.get('key')

        if certs == True:
            if ca and cert and key:
                pass
            else:
                raise ValidationError(_('If certs is checked, please fill in "ca", "cert" and "key".'))     
        else:
            ca = forms.CharField(required=False)
            cert = forms.CharField(required=False)
            key = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: How to solve what? What's the problem you are facing? You are telling us what you want but you didn't say what the issue is with your current code.

Comment: The problem is that it doesnt work as I expect it. When I do it like this, Django still wants the "ca", "cert" and "key" field filled. So, it doesnt apply the requirements changes I did in the last else.
And I ask for suggestions how I can achieve this (or maybe what I did wrong in this case)

Comment: Try opposite approach - make them `required=False` by default and enforce validation if `certs` is checked.

Comment: You cannot instantiate new fields like this. Your `else` clause in fact doesn't do anything, you're just assigning variables `ca`, `cert` to new fields, but those variables are local to the method anyway and don't do anything to your form. As @Gasanov mentioned, you should make the fields not required to start with and just raise the validation error as you do in the clean method (remove `else` clause). Make sure you also display `form.non_field_errors` somewhere in your template so that the specific error you raise is shown to the user.

Comment: Thank you and @Gasanov, this approach helped me to solve it!

Answer (score 2):

Although the primary way you’ll use `Field` classes is in `Form` classes, you can also instantiate them and use them directly to get a better idea of how they work. Each `Field` instance has a `clean()` method, which takes a single argument and either raises a `django.forms.ValidationError` exception or returns the clean value:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> f = forms.EmailField()
>>> f.clean('foo@example.com') 
'foo@example.com'
>>> f.clean('invalid email address')
Traceback (most recent call last): ... ValidationError: ['Enter a valid email address.']
```